# Актуальна ли на 2015 год книга по OpenGL "OpenGL — руководство по программированию, 4-е издание"

Tags: c++, книги, opengl

Я программист C#. Также занимаюсь 3D-моделированием(Maya,3ds max,ZBrush) Хочу изучить OpenGL + C++. Нашел книгу "OpenGL — руководство по программированию, 4-е издание" Девис, Нейдер, Шрайнер...

**Вопрос:** есть ли на сегодня (декабрь,2015г) смысл читать эту книгу, если я хочу использовать последнюю версию OpenGL? Поясню - вопрос не об абстрактном "есть ли смысл" а о конкретно актуальности этой книги на сегодня, чтобы как можно быстрее войти в курс дела и начать писать 3D программы на последней версии OpenGL.

К примеру [здесь](http://eax.me/books-issue-5/) есть комментарии которые вводят меня в заблуждение.
Там говорится об **устаревшем конвейере обработки графики** или что-подобное. И этому комментарию уже 2 года.

*P.S.* Очень трудно дается многое в OpenGL на сегодня. Конкретно это касается не языка C++, а логики 3D типа загадочных `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION),glOrtho..` и т.п., 3D-математики . Поэтому буду рад любой помощи и в этом вопросе.

Comment: Нет, она же 2015 года...
А если серьезно, то вопрос тут скорее не в актуальности, а в качестве изложенного материала.

Comment: @0xFFh про 2015 год не понял... Книга плохо изложена? Прошу посоветуйте тогда что почитать "чайнику" в этом вопросе.

Comment: @cvvvlad актуальность - субъективное понятие. в любом случае, книга по развивающейся прикладной технологии 2006-го года издания скорее всего будет неактуальна.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, эта книга 2006 года, её нет смысла начинать даже смотреть. Там действительно opengl перешел с фиксированного конвейера на программируемые шейдеры, и всё старое резко потеряло актуальность.

Вот актуальные на русском:

[**OpenGL ES 3.0. Руководство разработчика**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9780321933881%2C+9785970602560&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)

[**OpenGL 4. Язык шейдеров. Книга рецептов**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785970602553%2C+9781782167020&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)

Обе купил, хорошо написаны, хороший перевод. Первая, правда, это, скорее, подробный гайд по командам и синтаксису, вторая интересна с точки зрения уже приведенных в ней решений: всякие там туманы, освещение и прочее.
На русском это всё, что есть, из актуальных книг.

На английском — супербиблия openGL, 6 издание - OpenGL SuperBible: Comprehensive Tutorial and Reference (6th Edition)
http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4553108.

Rниги по opengl на английском можно найти спокойно на rutracker: наберите в поиске opengl — все что 2012,2013, 2014, 2015 года можно смотреть, читать, там уже более менее современное всё:

http://rutracker.org/forum/tracker.php?nm=opengl

Еще нужно учесть, что у openGL есть несколько разных версий, они похожи в целом. Есть openGL ES для браузеров и мобильных устройств — сейчас очень популярна, я в основном с ней работаю сам лично. Для PC, по-моему, openGL 4 версии сейчас актуален.

Если хочется ещё материала на русском:

Хорошая ветка на 4pda:
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=418429
и Startandroid. Начал цикл уроков по openGL, но там пока мало материала, что уж они там, куда доберутся и что напишут, я не знаю. http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/397-urok-168-opengl-vvedenie.html

Отдельные статьи по работе камеры, матрицам можно найти в gamedev.ru .
Мне иногда очень помогают, там хорошо расписана теория иногда.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за такое кол-во информации! Конкретный ответ, на конкретный вопрос. Ведь я мог уйти не в том направлении если бы не ваши ответы. С наступающим Новым Годом!

Answer (score 3):

Не имеет.

Вообще, настоятельно советую учить OpenGL по туториалам, а не по книгам. Некоторые туториалы имеют PDF версию, что делает их очень похожими на книги. В блоге, на который вы сослались, есть подборка [актуальных туториалов](http://eax.me/links-issue-31/), а также оригинальная [сериая туториалов](http://eax.me/opengl-simple-project/) на русском языке. Сейчас в серии всего 6 статей, но в скором времени должны появиться еще.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Мой комментарий к ответу @Evgeny Karavashkin также относится и к вам. СПАСИБО!